# Using SVG symbols in QGIS 3 that are not saved locally

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, svg

I am trying to design a QGIS (3.10.7) project which would enable users to work from home and not bind them to a specific computer at their workplace. I am using the PostgreSQL/PostGIS database to save data, and symbology is set beforehand in the empty project that the users will download. I found a problem regarding symbology when using this approach. I need to use SVG images as symbols for some layer and I would like to prevent downloading the whole library of them to local computers of the users, as there are around 400 unique images.

Is there a way that QGIS could get the images from my server?

I currently have them saved on the FTP server and they are publicly accessible, but I didn't find a way to load them in QGIS. I also thought about uploading them in the PostgreSQL database, but I am afraid it would be too much costly for the DB. Has anyone solved this or is local saving the only way?

Comment: Did you try the "From URL" in the SVG path field option ? if yes what didn't work ?

Comment: I put address in a format like this: xx.xxx.xxx.xx/styles/sdz/svg/A1a.svg (x stands for the IP address of the server) and question mark instead of an actual image appears. No other message pops up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that using 'Import from URL...' works fine, I just had to put "http://" in front of the server address.